# Creating static method to compare two strings char by char. Return true if all the letters in string a are in string b. Else, then return false

Tags: java, static

Here's my code so far. I got stuck and I don't know what to do. Thanks for the help!

```
public static boolean checkWord(String a, String b){

    int x = 0;
    while (x < a.length()){
      int y = 0;
      while (y < b.length()){
        if(a.charAt(x)==b.charAt(y)){
          String t = "next";
          System.out.println(t);
          y++;
        }else{

        }
      }
      x++;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: think about using `break` in your code. If you cannot find a char in the second string, then you should return false immediately. Otherwise return true at the end of the fnction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't compiled this code, but it should work.

```
public static boolean checkWord(String a, String b)
{
    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(j < b.length())
        {
            if(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(j)) break;
            j++;
        }
        if(j == b.length()) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

From what I understand, you want to see whether letters in 'a' are contained in 'b' in no particular order, i.e. you're not looking for whether 'a' is a substring of 'b'.

The outer loop will go through every single character in string a, whereas the inner loop will run however many times it takes to discover a match. If there is no match, the inner loop will have incremented it's control variable 'j' to size of 'b'. That's why you would do a check after the inner while loop - if the check passes, it means that a letter from string 'a' was not found anywhere in string 'b' and the program can therefore return false;

If the outer for loop finishes regularly, it means that all letters were matched, and the function will return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static boolean checkWord(String a, String b){
    int x = 0;
    while (x < a.length()){
      int y = 0;
      while (y < b.length()){
        System.out.println("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " a.charAt(x)==b.charAt(y):" + (a.charAt(x)==b.charAt(y)));
        if(a.charAt(x)==b.charAt(y)){
          break;
        }else{
          y++;
        }
        if (y == b.length()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      x++;
    }
    return true;
  }
```